# MS SQL temporary table missing field

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

Why MS-SQL does not throw error in this select?
There is no Document_ID field in #aa table.

```
 CREATE TABLE docs
 (
  Document_ID uniqueidentifier
 )

 SELECT 0x00 Document_XX
 INTO #aa


 SELECT * 
 FROM docs
 WHERE Document_ID IN (SELECT Document_ID FROM #aa)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Document_ID` in `SELECT Document_ID FROM #aa` would just resolve to the `docs.Document_ID`

It would be the same as

```
SELECT * 
FROM docs d
WHERE Document_ID IN (SELECT d.Document_ID FROM #aa)
```